# ETF's Market Cap Inconsistency

Tags: stocks, etf

I'm interested in buying NASDAQ:KWEB - which is a Chinese internet based ETF. However, I'm puzzled by the fact that different sources report **very** different market cap for this ETF:

[NASDAQ website](http://www.nasdaq.com/symbol/kweb) reports $3M,

[Google Finance](https://www.google.com/finance?q=KWEB&ei=lIDQUsiLHqzEwAPiUA) reports $14M.

The ETF's official website reports net assets (which is actually market cap, right?) of $26M

What's going on??

Comment: How often are market cap statistics updated by each provider for ETFs?

Comment: @JBKing - we are talking about 5X/9X-fold difference - it's weird if it's an updating-delay issue...

Comment: Did you notice the difference in dividend data between the providers? That for me would lead me to wonder how often are certain things being updated. Also, if the ETF uses 50,000 share creation/redemption units then that is approximately $1.7 million of market cap each time new shares are created or redeemed.

Comment: 3-14-26M market cap is **extremely** low.